# Filter all rows in a pandas DataFrame where a given value is between two column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**i already have this dataframe that contains two columns with floating number,i want to extract a dataframe based on this value 10.9 which is not on the dataframe, so that it will return the dataframe in the ranges of 10.9, look the table below**

```
   Words    Start_time(in sec)  End_time(in secs)   Time_per_words
0   let         0.1                 2.5                2.6
1   me          2.5                 2.6                5.1
2   tell        2.6                 2.9                5.5
3   you         2.9                 3.0                5.9
4   about       3.0                 3.2                6.2
5    4          10.7                11.0               21.7
```

**Expected Result: when i filter with the 3.10, i want to get this dataframe below, Thank you in advance**

```
   Words    Start_time(in sec)  End_time(in secs)   Time_per_words
4   4           10.7                11.0               21.7
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Build an [IntervalIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) if you intend to do this operation often:

```
val = 3.1
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(
    df['Start_time(in sec)'], df['End_time(in secs)'])

idx.contains(val)
#  array([False, False, False, False,  True])

df[idx.contains(val)]  

   Words  Start_time(in sec)  End_time(in secs)  Time_per_words
4  about                 3.0                3.2             6.2
```

Otherwise, this one-off boolean indexing op will suffice:

```
df[(df['Start_time(in sec)'] <= val) & (val <= df['End_time(in secs)'])]

   Words  Start_time(in sec)  End_time(in secs)  Time_per_words
4  about                 3.0                3.2             6.2
```

Comment: Liked the interval index approach.

Comment: thanks for the response, this didn't work here,
 df[(df['Start_time(in sec)'] <= val) & (val <= df['End_time(in secs)'])]
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Comment: Is val is single value or a list? @nath I assumed the former.

Comment: val is single value

Comment: @nath it works as I've shown here, there could be issues with your code so please debug through it

Comment: @cs95 can you please try it with this new dataframe of 10.9, i just updated the question instead of using 3.10 to 10.9, which i felt should works, thanks for the time, will continue debugging here

Comment: @cs5, it returns true, but does not return the actual value,
this the did not return the actual value df[idx.contains(val)] 
what version of pandas are u using

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH @cs5, it finally works, maybe is a mistake from me
Didn't work because i use an old variable which is a list containing the value, i did'nt get rid of it

df[(df['Start_time(in sec)'] <= val) & (val <= df['End_time(in secs)'])]

Comment: @cs5 if val is a list of values, what will i do please

Comment: @nath df.iloc[idx.get_indexer(vals)] would probably work if vals is a list.